# Rotating an object around it's centre in OpenGL

Tags: c#, opengl, 3d, rotation, opentk

I'm writing small 3d viewer of models from .obj file.
I have a car and I want to rotate car's wheels. I found a lot of [good](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/18854/rotating-an-object-in-opengl-about-its-centre) [examples](http://www.3dbuzz.com/forum/threads/154389-Change-the-center-of-rotation-in-OPENGL) but I still have a problem: wheel rotates around point at the it's border, not around center. You can see it on the [gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHnjt.jpg).
Below part of code without code for material and lighting. I find coordinates of wheel's center.

```
GL.PushMatrix();

// Rotate the car
GL.Translate(x, y, z); //x=0, y=0, z=0
GL.Rotate(ori, 0, 1, 0); // ori=90

// ...
// Material and lighting code 
// ...

foreach (var group in file.G)
{
    GL.PushMatrix();
    if (group.name == "wheel_rf")
    {
        float xTmp, yTmp, zTmp;
        xTmp = yTmp = zTmp = 0;
        int count = 0;
        // read group's faces
        foreach (var f in group.F)
        {
            // read face's vertices
            foreach (var v in f.V)
            {
                yTmp += v.Y;
                zTmp += v.Z;
                xTmp += v.X;
                count++;
            }
        }
        yTmp /= count;
        zTmp /= count;
        xTmp /= count;
        GL.Translate(xTmp, yTmp, zTmp);
        GL.Rotate(this.wheelAngle, 1, 0, 0);
        GL.Translate(-xTmp, -yTmp, -zTmp);
    }

    // draw faces for each group
    GL.Begin(file.PrimitiveType);
    foreach (var face in group.F)
    {
        GL.TexCoord2(face.VT[0]);
        GL.Normal3(face.VN[0]);
        GL.Vertex3(face.V[0]);

        GL.TexCoord2(face.VT[1]);
        GL.Normal3(face.VN[1]);
        GL.Vertex3(face.V[1]);

        GL.TexCoord2(face.VT[2]);
        GL.Normal3(face.VN[2]);
        GL.Vertex3(face.V[2]);
    }
    GL.End();
    GL.PopMatrix();
}
GL.PopMatrix();
```

Note! In first time I rotate all car on 90 degrees otherwise I would have seen the car back. I can't find reason of problem. Maybe trouble in the car model, but whole car is drawn fine.

Comment: You are iterating the faces, so you might count some vertices twice or more. You might want to average only on unique vertices. I don't think this is the solution, but it might help. Did you try swapping the ` GL.Translate(xTmp, yTmp, zTmp);` and `GL.Translate(-xTmp, -yTmp, -zTmp);` ?

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen About unique vertices I'll try it. In OpenGL transformation matrix must be in the opposite order. So first `GL.Translate(-xTmp, -yTmp, -zTmp)` - should translate to centre; second `GL.Rotate(this.wheelAngle, 1, 0, 0)`- rotate; `GL.Translate(xTmp, yTmp, zTmp)` - return to original coordinates. But in code it must be in opposite order. It's right in my code.